# Testing Model class equals() method using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

How do I test the Model class' `equals()` method. I keep experiencing the following issue:

```
 <<< FAILURE! - in EmployeeTest
testEquals(EmployeeTest)  Time elapsed: <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at EmployeeTest.testEquals(EmployeeTest.java:20)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

Sample test method. Using Mockito.verify() for testing equals method.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test your equals method, I recommend you to use a library like [Equalsverifier](http://www.jqno.nl/equalsverifier/) and not using a mock.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not want to use another library for equals.  Is there a way to test equals() using Mockito?

Comment: You should use JUnit and not mockito. You don't need a mock. Employee employee1 = new Employee("first", "last"); Employee employee2 = new Employee("first", "last"); AssertEquals(employee1, employee2).

Answer (score 0):

Mockito.verify() gives above issue.

```java
private static Employee mockedEmployee;
private static Employee employee;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    mockedEmployee = mock(Employee.class);
    employee = new Employee("first", "last");

    when(mockedEmployee .getFirstName()).thenReturn(Employee.getFirstName());
}

@Test
public void testEquals() {
    Mockito.verify(mockedEmployee).equals(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error message

> final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods. Those methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified.

so you will have to create real test object (not a mock) and then verify the `equals()` by comparing it with a real expected object.

Alternatively, you could instead verify other methods on the mock (i.e. verify that the last name was correctly set `verify(employee).setLastName("ExpectedLastName")`).